# Understanding an execution of the Monte Carlo tree search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, monte-carlo-tree-search

I have the execution of the Monte Carlo Tree Search (MCTS) below. I need to expand it, but I don't understand steps 1 and 2.

Why does it go to the first node and then make a new node, instead of going to the deepest left leaf? I thought it needs to go to the most probable leaf.

[image]

In step 1 of MCTS, it added a new node. Now, there are 9 cases.

[image]

In step 2 of MCTS, it added a new node. Now, there are 2 cases under the first node:

[image]